# Can you acquire Realm Gold (Realm Of The Mad God in-game credit) without spending real money?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I would like to know if there is any way you can get Realm Gold without spending *any* money. If you have a way, give a detailed description of how to get it.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2018, the [Discord Server](https://discord.gg/rotmg) has been running contests about twice a month that can reward up to 2500 Gold.

These contests are generally creative-based contests, such as creating new items, creating item sets based on already existing items, writing songs, or creating dungeon concepts. You'll be able to see them all in the #server-events channel, and instructions for how to enter are there.

Answer (score 0):

As it is not tradeable, there is no way to obtain Realm Gold except through real money purchase.